# How to break the loop when it is already found the matching value

Tags: c#, foreach

How to break the loop when the loop reads the value of the table and it's matching user input like the barcode, so it will not read all value in the table with a `-1` and show the `MessageBox` depending on how many `-1` on the table.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbladdbook WHERE fBarcodeNo LIKE '" + txtBARCODE.Text.Trim() + "%'";
                    cfgotcall.engageQuery(sql);
                    try
                    {
                        var result = Convert.ToInt32(cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fCurrentCopies"]);

                        foreach (DataRow row in cfgotcall.tbl.Rows)
                        {
                            if ((int)result == 1)
                            {
                                txtBARCODE_B.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0][9].ToString();
                            }
                            else if ((int)result == -1)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Book already borrowed.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch 
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Book not registered.");
                    }
```

EDIT: Question answered thanks guys! i use `break;`

Comment: Your answer is in your title.... `break;`

Comment: haha thanks it work!, boy i think i need a rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put

```
break;
```

.. at position that you want to stop foreach loop!

Answer (score 0):

..when it has found a matching value

```
else if ((int)result == -1) {
    MessageBox.Show("Book already borrowed.");
    break;
}
```